# For what values of $\theta \ge 1,$ the following integral is increasing and decreasing?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

Consider the integral:

$$I(\theta):=\int_{s=0}^{\infty} s e^{-(s-\theta)^2}ds, \theta \in [1, \infty).$$

**Questions:** (1) For what values of $\theta, I(\theta)$ increases and decrease? Full explanation would be greatly appreciated!

(2) What's the limit of the integrals $\lim_{\theta \to \infty} I(\theta)?$ How do you prove it? See the problem I'm facing is that I can't apply Monotone Convergence Theorem, as the integrand decreases for increasing $\theta$ only when $\theta \ge s. $ We can't also apply Dominated Convergence Theorem as we can't readily find an absolutely function $g \equiv g(\theta) \in L^1([0, \infty))$ dominating the integrand.

So how do proceed to find the limit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$Hint$ to determine increase function or not, you should check it derivative.

$$I(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(e^{-\theta^2} + \sqrt{\pi}\theta(\operatorname{erf}(\theta) +1)\right)$$

Hence $$I'(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}(1 + \operatorname{erf}(\theta))$$

According to $\operatorname{erf}(\theta) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\displaystyle \int_0^{\theta} e^{-x^2}dx > 0$. Now you may deduce the answer.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Could you please show, if possible, the first step in a bit more detail, where you found the alternate expression for $I(\theta)$ that you wrote in the second line of your answer? Thanks again!

Comment: @Stat_math this is just an calculation of your integral. $\int_0^{\infty} (s-\theta + \theta) \exp{-(s-\theta)^2} ds$

Comment: thanks again. But I'm checking with you about one point - I see that you found $I'(\theta) > 0 \forall \theta,$ meaning $I(\theta)$ always increases. But then as $\theta \to \infty,$ the integrand $\to 0,$ but here doesn't the integral $I(\theta)$ also converge to zero? If not, then what'd be the limit of $I(\theta)$ as $\theta \to \infty?$ I modified my OP with this question.

Comment: @Stat_math use dominant convergence theorem

Comment: Sorry but that's where I'm having problem - I can't find a absolute integrable function over $[0, \infty)$ dominating the integrand. I added the detail. And the answer isn't certainly zero as $I(\theta)$ increases. Could you please be a bit more detailed - may be modify your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Stat_math you even doesn't need to use dominant convergence theorem. Just use exact form, as presented in the answer.